# SSAS Prossessing using XMLA Script

Tags: deployment, ssas, xmla

When I deploy my SSAS solution using BIDS, it works perfectly.

[image]

Now, I want to deploy my solution using XMLA script (because I don't have have BIDS installed on the prod server)

I generated the XMLA script from the SSAS database
[image]

Now, I executed the same script on the same database, just for testing (so no need to change the connection string, access rights ...).

Then, when I try to process the cube using

```
<Process xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine">
  <Object>
    <DatabaseID>SD</DatabaseID>
  </Object>
  <Type>ProcessFull</Type>
  <WriteBackTableCreation>UseExisting</WriteBackTableCreation>
</Process>
```

The following error appear :

```
OLE DB error: OLE DB or ODBC error: Login failed for user 'OLAP'.; 28000.
```

Why does it work using BIDS and not using XMLA script ?
What could I do to correct this error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that when you generate XMLA script, it won't contain the password in the connection string (For security issue I suppose).

So the solution was to add pwd=yourPassword; in the connection string